# How to escape space in connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, connection-string

How to escape space in connection string using this example for (trusted mobile users).

I have a OU that is called `Trusted mobile users`:

```
connectionString="LDAP://floor.net/OU=USERS,OU=Trusted mobile users, DC=floor, DC=net"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape spaces in LDAP paths. You also should not have spaces after the commas:

```
connectionString="LDAP://floor.net/OU=USERS,OU=Trusted mobile users,DC=floor,DC=net"
```

If you're binding to a specific object (an OU in this case) the distinguished name (DN) you use should match exactly what is in the `distinguishedName` attribute of the object.

The only exception to this is is the forward slash (`/`). If the DN has a forward slash, you must escape it (by using `\/`) when you use it in an LDAP path, since that is used as a separator. For example, if your OU was called "Users / Groups", then your LDAP path would look like this:

```
LDAP://floor.net/OU=Users \/ Groups,OU=Trusted mobile users,DC=floor,DC=net
```

Comment: Can you give an example for what you explained and it is not working, I have tried \/ as a separator in the LDAP path inside web.config.

Comment: You don't need to use `\/` anywhere in your case.

Comment: but it is not working i have error.
by the way it is a connection string in web.config

Comment: Parser Error Message: The container specified in the connection string does not exist

Here is my connection string in web.config

    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://floor.net/OU=USERS,OU=Trusted mobile users,DC=floor,DC=net" />

Comment: Are you sure that `OU=USERS,OU=Trusted mobile users,DC=floor,DC=net` is exactly the `distinguishedName` of that OU? You can find it in AD Users and Computers by enabling "Advanced features" in the View menu, then right-click on the OU and click "Properties", then click the "Attribute Editor" tab and find "distinguishedName" in the list.

Comment: Yes it is : OU=Trusted mobile users, DC=floor,DC=net

Comment: What you just put in your comment is not a valid DN because it has a space after the comma.